# I am a genius, am/aren't I?

Tags: verbs, questions, tag-questions

There is a sentence "I am a genius", what should the tag question be?

> I am a genius, am I?

Or

> I am a genius, aren't I?

I've surfed the Internet and it says "aren't I", but why is it "aren't"? I do not understand.

And where can we say *am I?*

Answer (score 2):

You have good reason to be confused. There is nothing wrong with "am I" as a question tag. However, question tags attached to positive statements are most frequently formed as negative interrogatives. So

> I am a genius, am I not

is also grammatical and follows the more usual negative interrogative form. HOWEVER...

Question tags are far more common in spoken English than in written English. And in spoken English, contractions abound. There is, however, no generally accepted contraction for "am not" in modern English. (For more information, see the wikipedia entry for "ain't.") So, in speech and informal writing, "aren't I" is used as an **accepted** substitute for a true contraction of "am I not" although "are" and "am" are obviously different words. It is just one more irregularity to be learned for that most irregular of verbs "be."

EDIT: I want to clarify that "aren't" is not generally used as a substitute for a contraction of "am." In affirmative statements, "I am" has an accepted contraction in "I'm." In negative statements, "I am not" has an accepted contraction in "I'm not." In affirmative questions, "are I" is not grammatical at all. In negative questions, "are I not" is not grammatical. It is only in negative questions that "aren't I" is an accepted substitute for a true contraction of "am I not."

Comment: [**Amn't**](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-amn1.htm) is used in many Scottish and Irish dialects, almost exclusively in question tags, but you're correct that most English speakers don't have a contraction for "am not".

Comment: @CanadianYankee I have never been sure whether Lallands even is English. Of course, I am not sure that Yorkshire is English either. I am so parochial.

Answer (score 2):

The more common contraction of “am not” was “ain’t” in early Modern English, and before it was “ain’t” it was “an’t” . eventually, it became “ay” in some dialects (producing “ain’t”) and “ah” in some dialects (producing a word that sounded like “ahnt”).

And now for the final piece of the puzzle: “Ahnt” sounds exactly like “aren’t” in many non-rhotic dialects (dialects that don’t pronounce the /r/ in certain positions).

So “aren’t” is just a merger of “aren’t” plus “amn’t”/”ain’t”

Answer (score 0):

Aren't I? ≠ am I?: 'am I?' would fit better in some sentence like "I am *not* a genius, am I?", whilst 'aren't I?' works just fine when asking people for approval of your ingenuity.

Answer (score -1):

Question tags are mini-questions that we often put on the end of a sentence. In question tags we use an auxiliary verb (have, is, will, do...) depending on the verb in the sentence.

You normally use a *negative* question tag after a *positive* question.:

> Mary **will** be here soon, **won't** she?

You use a *positive* question tag after a *negative* question.:

> She **won't** be late, **will** she?

We use, *do, does, did* for the present and past simple.:

> She plays the piano, **doesn't** she?

Note that we say *aren't I ?* or *am I not?*:

> I am late, **aren't I** ? or I am late, **am I not**?

After *"Let's…"* the question tag is usually *shall we?*:

> Let's go for a walk, **shall we?**

After the imperative, the tag is usually *...will you?*:

> Open the door, **will you?**