# Question Tags- I Am

Tags: british-english, tag-questions

I am confused about the correct question tag for "I am ..."

Is it  "Am I not" or "Aren't I"?

Comment: *I'm commenting here, **aren't I?*** Or more colloquially, ***...ain't I**?* But even some native speakers feel uneasy about those, so they'll switch to the far more formal inversion ***...am I not**?*  even if they're the kind of speakers who would ***always*** use ***...aren't we**?* in preference to the relatively starchy ***...are we not**?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aren’t I? vs. Am I not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294712/aren-t-i-vs-am-i-not) Also [I am a genius, am/aren't I?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194319/i-am-a-genius-am-arent-i) and ["Aren't" instead "am not" for first person singular](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130896/arent-instead-am-not-for-first-person-singular), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 'am I not' and 'aren't I' are possible. The first is very formal and the second is normal in conversation and less formal writing.

[Aren't I or am I not (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/arent-i-or-are-i-not-correct-usage)